# Apache NiFi deployment in production

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to Apache NiFi. From the documentation, I could understand that NiFi is a framework with a drag and drop UI that helps to build data pipelines. This NiFi flow can be exported into a template which is then saved in Git.

Are we supposed to import this template into production NiFi server? Once imported, are we supposed to manually start all the processors via the UI? Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Templates are just example flows to share with people and are not really meant for deployment. Please take a look at NiFi Registry and the concept of versioned flows.

https://nifi.apache.org/registry.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_qhRVChjZY&feature=youtu.be

https://bryanbende.com/development/2018/01/19/apache-nifi-how-do-i-deploy-my-flow

Comment: Hi Bryan, what if we want to create multiple flow (process group) in same instance with different processors parameters for different users. How is it possible, if it is how we can approach to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Template is xml representation of your process structure (processors, processor groups, controllers, relationships etc). You can upload it to another nifi server for deploy. You also can start all the processors by nifi-api.